# Error in prediction when plotting an ROC curve in R?

Tags: r, prediction, roc

So I am trying to plot an ROC curve in R using ROCR package. I have a binary outcome named Health and a continuous variable named test_result.

```
dat$health <- as.numeric(dat$health == "healthy") 
mod <- glm(health ~ test_result, data=dat, family="binomial")
pred1 <- prediction(predict(mod), dat$health)
```

When I try running the last line of prediction(), I get an error saying

```
Number of predictions in each run must be equal to the number of labels for each run.
```

So I looked up the length for predict(mod) and dat$health and I got 1306 and  1366 respectively. Does this difference in lengths cause the error? If so, why does the length of predict(mod) come out to be less than the length of the outcome variable? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Probably you have missing values in the data and since you can’t predict on missing values your prediction vector is shorter than your actual vector. Excluding the rows with missing values should help. dat[compete.cases(day), ] should do the trick.

Comment: @TimTeaFan wow you are correct.. that was so stupid..

Comment: It’s am common error and I encountered it myself often enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here. You are predicting without any data in predict function. It should be as follows

```
pred1 <- prediction(predict(mod, dat), dat$health)
```